# How i keep message after i ban someone with the bot?

Tags: discord.py

When I ban someone with my bot, all recent message get deleted, so I was wonder if is there a way to keep messages.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason = None):
  ban = await ctx.reply(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{loading_emoji}  Banning {user.mention} from `server1` and `server2`...', color = 0x00BF23), mention_author=True)
  s1 = await bot.fetch_guild(server1)
  s2 = await bot.fetch_guild(server2)
  await s1.ban(user, reason = reason)
  await s2.ban(user, reason = reason)
  await asyncio.sleep(0.9)
await ban.edit(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Success!', description = f'{shield_emoji}  Banned {user.mention} from `server1` and `server2`!', timestamp = datetime.utcnow(), color = 0x00BF23), mention_author=True)
```

Edit: So i checked and i just needed to add `delete_message_days=0` in `await s1.ban(user, reason = reason)` so should look like this `await s1.ban(user, reason = reason, delete_message_days=0)` thx for the help

Comment: See `delete_message_days` argument in [`Guild.ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Guild.ban).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delete_message_days (int) Parameter in Guild.ban

[Api Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=ban#discord.Guild.ban)